# Passing current location to Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I am writing an application that opens the Maps app and I would like to be able to add a `Marker` object at the current location when it opens. My application correctly opens the Maps app and shows a blue dot for my current location, but I am having difficulty using that current location in order to create a `Marker`.

Here is my source code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PlaceMarker extends FragmentActivity 
    implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient = null;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest = null;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;
    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
    private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 1;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location location = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_marker);

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        if (servicesConnected()) {
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

            Double mLatitude = getCurrentLocation().getLatitude();
            Double mLongitude = getCurrentLocation().getLongitude();

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude))
                .title("Title Test")
                .snippet("Snippet Test"));
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Position unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        }
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    private Location getCurrentLocation() {
        Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

        if (location != null) {
            return location;
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Current Location Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            checkforGPSAndPromptOpen();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void checkforGPSAndPromptOpen() {
        boolean enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!enabled) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    // Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity by Google Play services
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Decide what to do based on the original request code
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST : 
            // If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try to connect again
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK :
                    // Try the request again
                    break;
                }
            }
     }

    private boolean servicesConnected() {
        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d("Location Updates", "Google Play services is available.");
            // Continue
            return true;
        // Google Play services was not available for some reason
        } else {
            // Get the error code
            // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
            if (errorDialog != null) {
                errorDialog.show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the client finishes successfully.
     * At this point, you can request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
        location = getCurrentLocation();
        takeToLocation(convertLocationtoLatLong(location));
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Report to the UI that the location was updated
//      String msg = "Updated location: " + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," + Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
//      Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    private void takeToLocation(LatLng newLocation) {
        if (newLocation != null) {
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newLocation, 16);
            mMap.animateCamera(update);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Position unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private LatLng convertLocationtoLatLong(Location location) {
        LatLng currentLatLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        return currentLatLong;
    }
}
```

The logcat error shows that there is an `IllegalStateException: Not connected` caused by line 61:

```
Double mLatitude = getCurrentLocation().getLatitude();
```

Comment: GPS is turned off on your device maybe? No Internet connection available?

Comment: @Stan GPS is definitely turned on as it wouldn't show the blue dot at my current location if it was off. This one really has me stumped because I can comment out the `mLatitude`, `mLongitude`, and `addMarker()` lines and it will open up Maps perfectly, showing a blue dot at my current location. As soon as I comment those lines back in, I get the `IllegalStateException` error complaining about no connection.

Comment: I beleive that AOS caches your last location so to know it you don't need to turn on GPS system. So "GPS is definitely turned on as it wouldn't show the blue dot at my current location if it was off" might not be that clear. Also I managed current location using Location services instead of asking it from map.

Comment: @Stan That would explain a lot if that is the case. I have tried to manage the current location in that way using the `getCurrentLocation()` method in my code. This is actually how I am attempting to pass the latitude and longitude back to the variables. Is this what you mean by using Location services or do you have a better example?

Comment: Also you are using Google Play Services so maybe its the point? Maybe its that service cant connect? Also try to clean the project - maybe eclipse points you to the wrong code line. Also if it is really line 61 where you call getCurrentLocation() - it cant be so cuz getCurrentLocation() is your method and error has to be catched inside that method body instead of line where its being called from.

Comment: @Stan In my `servicesConnected()` method, I have it set to log the output that "Google Play services is available" if it connects successfully. I see this in my log, so it seems like it does connect. It is also the condition that I check to be `true` before initiating the latitude and longitude, so it would seem that it is able to connect just before the error.

Comment: what gonna happen if getCurrentLocation() returns null? Did you clean the project?

Comment: @Stan Thanks! For some reason, your question inspired the answer for me. I moved the initiation of my latitude and longitude variables to my `onConnected()` method and I moved my `Marker` declaration as well. Finally got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you have some third party crash catching SDK used in your project then if getCurrentLocation() returns null in following lines:

```
    Double mLatitude = getCurrentLocation().getLatitude();
    Double mLongitude = getCurrentLocation().getLongitude();
```

it could happen that SDK catches the NPE but fails to send a report. cuz your method getCurrentLocation() could return null:

```
    Toast.makeText(this, "Current Location Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    checkforGPSAndPromptOpen();
    return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my logcat error, I seemed to have overlooked the suggestion:

```
Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
```

Since this is where my LocationClient requests a location update and gets my current location, I moved my latitude and longitude initiations as well as my `addMarker()` code within this method.

```
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
        location = getCurrentLocation();
        takeToLocation(convertLocationtoLatLong(location));

        Double mLatitude = getCurrentLocation().getLatitude();
        Double mLongitude = getCurrentLocation().getLongitude();

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude))
            .title("Title Test")
            .snippet("Snippet Test"));
    }
```